# CakePHP custom search according to date

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I want to search data from table according to branch_id or date or in between dates.

What should be the Query in CakePHP.

**Query in Controller:**

```
$branchId = $_GET['data']['BranchDailyReport']['branch_id'];
$from_date = $_GET['data']['BranchDailyReport']['from_date'];
$to_date = $_GET['data']['BranchDailyReport']['to_date'];
$condition = array('OR' => array('BranchDailyReport.branch_id =' => $branchId,
                    'BranchDailyReport.date <= ' => $from_date,
                    'BranchDailyReport.date >= ' => $to_date
                )
            );
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using the https://github.com/CakeDC/search plugin?

Comment: no i am not using this Plugin..

Comment: You might want to.. Also, using $_GET directly is not a good practice in CakePHP. Last but not least: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the BETWEEN MySql operator

```
$condition = array('OR' => array('BranchDailyReport.branch_id =' => $branchId,
                'BranchDailyReport.date BETWEEN ? AND ? ' => array($from_date, $to_date)
            )
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

To find a date between two dates, that needs to be an AND.
You could use an AND inside your OR condition to find between two dates:

```
$conditions = array(
    'OR' => array(
        'BranchDailyReport.branch_id =' => $branchId,
        'AND' => array(
            'BranchDailyReport.date <= ' => $from_date,
            'BranchDailyReport.date >= ' => $to_date
        )
    )
);
```

By the looks of that form, you don't want "branch_id OR date OR in between dates" .. you might want branch_id AND in between dates"...

```
$conditions = array(
    'BranchDailyReport.branch_id =' => $branchId,
    'BranchDailyReport.date <= ' => $from_date,
    'BranchDailyReport.date >= ' => $to_date
);
```

(side note)
Also, if you're using CakePHP, you should be using `$this->request->data` to access `$_GET` variables.  If you're in a model, than pass `$this->request->data` as a function parameter.